# Magento 2 extension submission to the marketplace was failed

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, plugin, marketplace

```
"command": "composerConfigRepository0",
                        "output": [
                            "Finished with the '0' exit code."
                        ]
```

I made my own plugin and tried putting it on the marketplace. But it didn't pass the technical review and there's an error in the first line of the report JSON. Can you help me fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this things.

1. In that same report, search this line :

> "Finished with the '1' exit code."

2. Read the comment below that line, because that line tell you the actual error into this extensions.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I couldn't find that particular line in my report.

Comment: Confirm, you are download the proper report.

Comment: I have checked once again and couldn't find any